# Parser for multidigit numbers

Tags: python

recently I had a problem in an assignment where the postfix expression calculation worked only on digits, not on multi-digit numbers, now my solution works, although I don't know how to create a parser or tokenizer, in this case BNF or other possible. I know that the solution below is not very good, but unfortunately I don't know how to start. To be clear, I am using the stack class, full code here: https://pastebin.com/a3vc19gr

Here the code with the problem that does not work:

```
def parser(char):
    if char in "0123456789": 
        token.append(char) 
    else: 
        yield "".join(token) 
    if char in "+-*": 
        yield char
```

Using it there, there is also a function, generator to_numbers, that you can see in the link above.

```
    stack = Stack()
    data = parser(data)
    for token in data:
        if isinstance(token, numbers.Number):
            stack.push(token)
```

Then im getting this error

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not generator
```

Using Python 3.9

Comment: Apparently `char` is a generator and not a string? Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

something wrong with data object, it should be char not a 'generator'

Comment: data is nothing else but expressions that im using as an input :|

Comment: take at a look at code 【data = parser(data)】 here, you pass data to parser and in [parser] function, you treat data as char.  I think you should write something like these:`for c in data: another_var = parser(c)`